# Datepickers as table

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using the following code to generate multiple datepickers based on a time interval:

In my html:

```
 <div class="datePickerClass"></div>
```

In my js:

```
 $(".datePickerClass").datepicker({
         defaultDate: new Date(startYear, startMonth, 1),
         numberOfMonths: numberOfDisplayedMonths,          
});
```

So for the example above I will have generated 5 datepickers (this can be any number, it will be received as a parameter the function (startMonth,startYear)) on the same page, each for a month. The problem is that I want them on the same row, but they are generated on a new row. I tried to use a class for the datepicker, but I will always have different numbers based on numberOfMonths variable. Is there any way I can put them in a table?

Comment: Row? where? We need more info.

Comment: I edited my post with a photo. Right now the datepickers are displayed on a column, but I want them near each other

Comment: What does the generated html look like for each row? Is each row wrapped in a div or tr?

Comment: It is rapped in a div like this ```<div class="datePickerClass"></div>``` With tr I tried but it didn't work. The problem is that I only have one div, because I don't know how many datepickers I will be generating untill the date interval is selected (after the interval is selected, multiple datepickers are generated from js function)

Comment: Like `<div class="datePickerClass"><div>1st cal</div><div>2nd call</div></div>` or like `<div class="datePickerClass"><div><div class="datePickerClass"><div>...`

Comment: I only have one div, as I pointed out in my comment above. I edited my post with my html code and my js function that generate the date pickers

Comment: If you end up with only one div, `.datePickerClass {display: flex;}` will layout the child elements like you want.